# Unknown 'sensorNamePerso' field in where clause

Tags: php, pdo

I do not know why but when I compile my code, I get this error, I tried to put the quotation marks because sensorNamePerso is a string but it does not change anything, can you help me please ?

```
<?php

     $condi = "WHERE sensorId=".$sensors_id[1]." AND typeId= ".$type_id[1]." AND sensorNamePerso= ".$sensors_name_perso[1]."  AND date >= DATE_ADD(now(),INTERVAL -1 MONTH) ORDER BY date DESC";
     $value2 = $database->sqlRequest("SELECT value FROM historysensor ".$condi, "value");
     $date2 = $database->sqlRequest("SELECT date FROM historysensor ".$condi, "date");


?>
```

It's just a little part of my code

[historySensor table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgwDM.png)

[usersensor table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6L3pl.png)

Comment: Show use your `historysensor` table

Comment: Ok (just look on my question, you'll see the capture of my historysensor table)

Comment: Ye I see the problem already, your table doesn't even have a `sensorNamePerso` field, maybe it is from anohter table?

Comment: Yes sensorNamePerso it's from another table, do I need to do a JOIN ?

Comment: Yes you do need to use `JOIN` than

Comment: how should I do that in PDO ? I'm not an expert in PDO yet

Comment: This is something in SQL but if you show me the other table I can maybe try it

Comment: Thank you, just look on my question(again), you'll see the capture of the other table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this works for you now

```
<?php

     $condi = "WHERE historysensor.sensorId=".$sensors_id[1]." AND historysensor.typeId= ".$type_id[1]." AND usersensor.sensorNamePerso= ".$sensors_name_perso[1]."  AND historysensor.date >= DATE_ADD(now(),INTERVAL -1 MONTH) ORDER BY date DESC";
     $value2 = $database->sqlRequest("SELECT value FROM historysensor INNER JOIN usersensor ON usersensor.typeId=historysensor.typeId ".$condi, "value");
     $date2 = $database->sqlRequest("SELECT date FROM historysensor INNER JOIN usersensor ON usersensor.typeId=historysensor.typeId ".$condi, "date");


?>
```

Comment: Thank you , now it gives me this error (Unknown 'pressure' field in where clause)

Comment: Thats weird , because I never used any field with the name pressure in this sql statement, is it possible you have multiple querys in your file?

Comment: Yes I have a lot of queries in my file, I didn't put the whole file because my post would have been really long.

Comment: I see it, i think this sql statement works but you made the same mistake in other querys. But i can be wrong ofcourse

Comment: Good luck , i hope I helped you so far

Comment: The fact that sensorNamePerso is a string is not a problem?

Comment: No that wouldn't be a problem

Comment: Ok, I can't find where this problem comes from, I think I'm going to delete those queries and go on something else.

Comment: Oke  if this answer helped you leave the green mark on my answer. If you have more questions just let me know or make a new question!